# Image/Video resolutions and different formats in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, media, resolution, file-format, fal

Is there a preferred way to implement this?

The cropVariant makes multiple resolutions for images kind of possible, but still a lot of things are missing here.

What do you think about another nested relation inside the `sys_file_metadata` to other files (having different resolutions or formats, but no own metadata as the content is the same), so a user could handle one media file as the base and add different variants to its metadata relation, so that those related files automatically appear on input like alt text, description, etc. do.

Then additionally one could also create the same relation in `sys_file_reference` to be able to overwrite the relations on single instances, but I think I don't need that.

Do some of you know if there will be a core feature soon, because I don't want to create my custom solution if I would need to rewrite it soon in the future.

I found this feature request [#27391 Allow multiple formats/resolutions for media-content](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/27391) which seems like there are no current plans.

Comment: What is stopping you from developing this feature for the TYPO3 core and submitting it as a patch? If I were you, I would think about a concept and post it in the Forge issue you mentioned. In parallel, it might make sense to ask for support for the concept and implementation in the TYPO3 Slack channel #typo3-cms-coredev.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'm not sure if I have enough knowledge about TYPO3 framwork functions and all side effects that need to be considered with localization, workspaces etc. but you are right if I figure out a good and bit more detailed idea or maybe a base to start with I'll do so. Thank for your help ;)